# How do I show my fab on scroll when the first item in the recycler view is not visible but hide when the first item is visible?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, recyclerview-layout

So I am trying to implement a FAB button such that, when I scroll my recycler view and the first item is not visible (scrolled up etc) , fab button should be visible, else it should be hidden if the first position is showing. Right now I have implemented the code, but it doesn't show the fab button at all, just wanted to know what I am doing wrong?

my xml code is below:

```
<Linearlayout ....


    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pullToRefreshLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/emailFab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/myRecyclerView"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                app:layout_behavior="com.example.fab.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
                />
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

my Kotlin code is below:

```
val positionView = (myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
                if (dy >0 && positionView > 0) {
                    emailFab.show();
                } else  {
                    emailFab.hide();
                }
            }
```

Any ideas how to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it FAB in every RecyclerView child or one FAB in activity? (as e.g in Gmail app send button)

Comment: r u for real ;) well u can make a simple interface for that and track the movement of recyclerview and track if the first child is visible using the linearlayout manager wait leme give you somme code

Comment: @Domin let me update the code to show how I am using fab in xml etc,. hope that'll help

Comment: updated the code with xml , all there is to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you should pull the `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` into the `OnScrollListener` to find visible position in scroll changes:

```
myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            val positionView = (myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()

            if (positionView > 0) {
                if(!emailFab.isShown) {
                    emailFab.show();
                }
            } else  {
                if(emailFab.isShown) {
                    emailFab.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for, easy and works perfectly! Thanks @aminography!

Comment: You're welcome :-) I'm very glad to see the problem is solved.

Comment: any idea about my question, about uploading an image to server? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598276/how-do-i-pass-a-multi-part-body-parameter-for-rxjava2-androidnetworking-post-req  (I have included a working okhttp client recommendation from postman, just need help converting it to the androidnetworking library i am using)

Comment: it Stay ugly without animation :(

Comment: @lukecross: Calling `show()` and `hide()` on a fab will cause animated appearing and disappearing. What's your exact problem?

Comment: I was using old version, in AndroiDx the animation appear and is beautiful, sorry!

Comment: No problem dude

Answer (score 1):

This code is 100% working:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "TestActivity";

    private ArrayList<String> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    private FloatingActionButton fabButton;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;

    private boolean isFabVisible = false;

    private OnFabVisibilityCallback onFabVisibilityCallback;

    public void setOnFabVisibilityCallback(OnFabVisibilityCallback onFabVisibilityCallback) {
        this.onFabVisibilityCallback = onFabVisibilityCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_contacts);

        datas.add("one");
        datas.add("two");
        datas.add("three");
        datas.add("four");
        datas.add("five");
        datas.add("six");
        datas.add("seven");
        datas.add("eight");
        datas.add("nine");
        datas.add("ten");

        fabButton = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fabButton);
        fabButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, datas);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if(linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 0){
                    //hide
                    if(onFabVisibilityCallback != null){
                        onFabVisibilityCallback.onChange(false);
                    }
                }else{
                    //show
                    if(onFabVisibilityCallback != null){
                        onFabVisibilityCallback.onChange(true);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        setOnFabVisibilityCallback(new OnFabVisibilityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean isVisible) {
                if(isVisible){
                    if(!isFabVisible){
                        isFabVisible = true;
                        fabButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }else{
                    if(isFabVisible){
                        isFabVisible = false;
                        fabButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

        private Activity activity;
        private ArrayList<String> datas;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public DataAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> datas) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.datas = datas;
            this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new SimpleViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.unit_test, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            ((SimpleViewHolder)holder).init(datas.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return datas.size();
        }

        private class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            private TextView text;

            public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                initViews(itemView);
            }

            private void initViews(View v){
                text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }

            public void init(String data){
                text.setText(data);
            }

        }

    }

    public interface OnFabVisibilityCallback{

        void onChange(boolean isVisible);

    }

}
```

The activity layout files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is recyclerview child layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="data"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is there no easier way to do this? this seems to be unnecessarily complex. Is there an easier way to detect if the first row is visible without having to create an interface for change fallback and then using that as a callback and then using that callback within the scroll listener?

Comment: well this is just for the sake of demonstration you can take another approach in which you can create your custom recyclerview which gives you an overridden method to set FAB visibility in that case code will be divided into files and will be lot easier but the basic remains the same you will have to listen for the scroll change in linearlayoutmanager and set an interface to call the method. hope you undertand that